# How to get the loss function used in NetTrain?

Tags: neural-networks

When the third argument to `NetTrain` is set to `Automatic`, how can you tell what loss function it actually used and extract it?

Looking at the docs, I don't see it as a property that can be asked for in the fourth argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree it would be nice if you could query this information interactively from the progress window after starting a training session. But using a property (4th argument of `NetTrain`) you can explicitly ask for the 'loss network', which is the network in which loss layers have been attached and which is used to actually do the training.

```
net = LinearLayer[];
data = {1 -> 1.9, 2 -> 4.1, 3 -> 6.0, 4 -> 8.1};
NetTrain[net, data, Automatic, "LossNet", MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]
```

In this case you'll see it is a `NetGraph` that uses a `MeanSquaredLossLayer`. If the net already has loss layers the loss network is typically the same as the training network.

The actaul internal function is `` NeuralNetworks`AttachLoss[net, spec] `` if you want access to it directly. You can leave `spec` off if you just want the automatic choice.

Comment: The "LossNet" argument does not appear to work in version 11.3. Is there a new way to get the information?

Answer (score 2):

In the doc of `NetTrain`,it says

> When a loss layer is chosen *automatically* for a port, the loss layer to use is based on the layer within the net *whose output is connected to the port*

[image]

Comment: But what is it exactly, are there explicit rules for each type of layer?